# C#/WPF/XAML/SQLite - Populating two bound fields

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm really struggling to populate/bind two textblocks on a XAML form to a query (I'm new to WPF/C#).  So far, I haven't found any examples that provide me with a version of the C# and the XAML:

```
    _con.Open();
    var com = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT [ActivityID], [Activity_Category] FROM tblActivity")
        Connection = _con,
        CommandType = CommandType.Text

    ?????  

    _con.Close();
```

I think I can figure out the XAML/binding commands - but am stumped about how write the c#(as I said, I'm really new to this).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want help with displaying your data or retrieving your data via DQLite or all of it? Could you eventually be more specific?

Comment: Sorry Andreas - I need help with the C# code to pull the data, which is then presented to the XAML form.  Whilst I do not fully know how to bind the two textblocks to the query, I think I can find the solution (once the C# is working).  I am using the directive "System.Data.SQLite;"

Comment: Did you already see this tutorial? http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Comment: Thanks again Andreas that's really helpful. However, where I get lost is in the section "while (reader.Read())" - I need to populate the two textblocks on the XAML form and am not sure what to change the code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just as an example, here are some [ViewModels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), while I'm, assuming, that you do not want to read just one single pair of ID/Category, but rather a bunch of ID/Category pairs.

```
public class ActivityViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string Category { get; private set; }

    public ActivityViewModel(string id, string category)
    {
        Id = id;
        Category = category;
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    private const string TABLE_NAME = "tblActivity";
    private const string COLUMN_NAME_ID = "ActivityID";
    private const string COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY = "Activity_Category";

    private SQLiteConnection _con;

    public IEnumerable<ActivityViewModel> Activities { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _con = new SQLiteConnection(...); // create your connection
        readFromDb();
    }

    private void readFromDb()
    {
        var list = new List<ActivityViewModel>();

        _con.Open();
        var sqlText = string.Format(
            "SELECT [{0}], [{1}] FROM {2}",
            COLUMN_NAME_ID,
            COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY,
            TABLE_NAME);
        var sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlText, _con);
        using(var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                var id = reader[COLUMN_NAME_ID] as string;
                var category = reader[COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY] as string;
                var newPair = new ActivityViewModel(id, category);
                list.Add(newPair);
            }
        }

        _con.Close();

        Activities = list;
    }
}
```

If you really just want right two values, you could discard the `ActivityViewModel` and leave out the while loop (since it reads as long as the command returns result lines)

```
    private void readFromDb()
    {
        var list = new List<ActivityViewModel>();

        _con.Open();
        var sqlText = string.Format(
            "SELECT [{0}], [{1}] FROM {2} LIMIT 1",
            COLUMN_NAME_ID,
            COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY,
            TABLE_NAME);
        var sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlText, _con);
        using(var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            this.Id = reader[COLUMN_NAME_ID] as string;
            this.Category = reader[COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY] as string;
        }

        _con.Close();
    }
```

The remaining step is then the data binding, whereby a ViewModel is the DataContext of the view (e.g. a UserControl or a Window). But you said, you'll find your way to data binding, maybe you read through MVVM concept of WPF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks Andreas (once again).  Whilst this approach may be the right one, going down the MVVM before I have a solid foundation in OOP - maybe a step too far.  What I desperately need, is a tweak to my code (that runs in the XAML.cs file), so that I can bind the two fields.  I only need to display a single record (based on the queries WHERE clause).  My apologies and appreciation for all of your help.

Comment: This is no Problem, you may just use the second code snippet inside your ...xaml.cs file (called the 'code behind') and just add 2 properties: Id, Category.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help - I got a lot of great info from this -  really appreciated.